# Запятая после «также»

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая после «также» в этих случаях:

```
Также ? в сегодняшнем выпуске мы обсудим следующие темы: <...>

Мы обсудим все ? что касается политики, а также ? следующие темы: <...>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Запятую необходимо ставить после вводных слов (в большинстве случаев).  Слово *также* вводным не является.  *Также* - это союз, синоним союзу *и*.  Поэтому запятая не нужна ни в первом, ни во втором случае.

> Также в сегодняшнем выпуске мы обсудим следующие темы: <...>
>
> Мы обсудим всё, что касается политики, а также следующие темы: <...>

Стоит также отметить, что Грамота.ру [не советует](http://hghltd.yandex.net/yandbtm?text=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D1%81%20%22%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B6%D0%B5%22&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.gramota.ru%2Fspravka%2Fburo%2F%3Fpage%3D2466&fmode=inject&mime=html&l10n=ru&sign=af04fe8377f5c6261bb1247e04b2d97f&keyno=0) начинать предложения со слова *также*, хотя исключения бывают в зависимости от контекста. На мой взгляд, первое из этих предложение подпадает под это исключение.

Comment: "Стоит также отметить" - хороший пример, демонстрирующий употребление _также_.

Answer (score 2):

Также в сегодняшнем выпуске мы обсудим следующие темы: <...>

Мы обсудим всё, что касается политики, а также следующие темы: <...>

Comment: Объясните, пожалуйста, чем диктуется отсутствие запятых (я согласен, что они не нужны в данных случаях).